# Is there a good strategy to have alternative code?

Tags: git

I was asked to create a feature, but not deploy it and have it ready to deploy at any time. I don't know when or if it will be deployed.

What is a good way to manage this code?

I thought of keeping it on a separate branch, but then I need to constantly rebase this alternate branch on master. Also, if I change the same code (which could be app or test) in master, then I will have a merge conflict, and every time I update the same code on master I'll need to handle the merge conflict on the alternate branch code.

So that seems like a complicated, error-prone and labor intensive approach.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Also, what is the correct way to describe this "alternate code"?

Working with Git.

Answer (score 2):

Your best alternative is a [feature switch](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html). Frankly, branches should be done when changes are widespread and liable to be open for a fairly short time.

In addition to the other risks you noted, there is the fact that as things sit out on a branch, there really are no guaranteed way to know they are being maintained. You can setup your CI system to build that branch (no one does). But that is just more management (advantage though is that at least you will know if it starts to necrify).

Comment: Code on the disabled side of a feature switch can also bit-rot, but at least people can *see* that it's there.

Comment: Of course, but the feature switched code is also a subset, right? In the case of a branch, you are freeze drying every line of code in the app/module.

Comment: What if it involves database migrations or other breaking changes to existing code?

Comment: Then you can't do it. Or you have to have a temporary sidecar in the db until you are ready to make the complete flip over.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this too, but it seemed like a poor solution in this situation since we may never use it...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is best practice, but what about this?

`#define ENABLE_SOME_FEATURE`

```c
#ifdef ENABLE_SOME_FEATURE
    /* do some code stuff */
#endif
```

Comment: If your language supports this feature, this is the way to go. Doesn't work so good in e.g. Java or Python.